# Spring Jax-ws in standalone application endpoints on different ports

Tags: java, spring, web-services, jax-ws

I am running Standalone Spring Jaxws Application and am using org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter to expose webservice , endpoints are
  127.0.0.1:9595/MyFirstService' and 127.0.0.1:9595/MySecondService . Now i want to expose my web services on diffent ports like code 127.0.0.1:9595//MyFirstService and 127.0.0.1:8585/MySecondService'.

Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: I think the only way to do is to have two different service applications. The service (application) is started on one port. To change to another port you would then have to start the service on a different port.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution .

I was using  org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter

Now i changed it to

```
  <jaxws:endpoint id="sampleReq" implementor="#request" address="localhost:9090/MyFirstService" >
 </jaxws:endpoint>
```

```
  <jaxws:endpoint id="sampleReq2" implementor="#request2" address="localhost:8585/MySecondService" >
 </jaxws:endpoint>
```

Comment: Does that work? So let's you hosted that on tomcat. Your server would have one port say 9090. Now if you add define another port for another service operation, 8585, as in you case, how is that going to work? Unless of course if you're re-routing requests to 8585 to 9090.

Comment: Am running this app as standalone application like i mentioned in my title. it worked for me